# How to load a Bluetooth .apk file in Android G1 phone through Linux OS?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to install a Bluetooth Application over my G1 device in linux environment. What is the correct procedure for this?

Whenever I am installing the application the following error is thrown:-

**adb install /home/parveen/workspace/BluetoothChat/bin/BluetoothChat.apk
        337 KB/s (28084 bytes in 0.081s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/BluetoothChat.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]****

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems to indicate that the application is already installed!

However, to reinstall the application....

```
adb install -r /home/parveen/workspace/BluetoothChat/bin/BluetoothChat.apk
```

"-r" means reinstall